# How to change the position of my axis labels in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have some labels on my y-axis that look like this:

[image: labels]

However, I want them to be positioned by the tick mark (I've drawn an arrow showing where I want to position them). Is it possible to shift my labels? or even just change the position of my tick-mark to match the label?

Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var yticks = ['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3', 'Step 4', 'Step 5', 'Step 6'];

    //some asp calls to my c# code to get points
    var customers = <%=getCustomersForLineGraph()%>;
    var points = <%=getMainLineGraphPoints()%>;

    var plot3 = $.jqplot('linegraph', points,
      {
          title: 'All Companies Completion Status',

          axes: {
              xaxis: {
                  renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                  label: 'Work Weeks',
                  max: 55,
                  min: 0,
                  tickOptions: {
                      formatString: '%.0f',
                  },
              },
              yaxis: {

                  label: 'Phases',
                  renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                  labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,

                  ticks: yticks
              }
          },
      }
    );

});
```

**I Solved it!**

I was able to add my labels by specifying the ticks like this:

```
yaxis: {                      
    label: 'Phases',                 

    ticks: [[1," "],[2,'Step 1'],[3,'Step 2'],[4,'Step 3'],[5,'Step 4'],[6,'Step 5'],[7,'Step 6']]
       }
```

I figured I would leave this question up in case someone else runs into a similar problem (someone on SO let me know if this is not the correct protocol). Thanks

Comment: when I change the renderer to $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer and replace my labels with numbers it lines up correctly

Comment: I've also tried using: "labelRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisLabelRenderer" and  "tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer" without any luck